# How to use variable in JMESPath expression?

Tags: json, jmespath

The regular expression works perfect as below:
jmespath.search(currentStats, 'Items[?Name == `Annie`]')

But I want to make my filtered key as a variable.

I have tried
var name = "Annie"
`jmespath.search(JSONdata, 'Items[?Name ==` %s`]' %name;`)

Which does not work.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using? I would guess Python but I would like to be sure.

Comment: Actually with the semicolon it can't be Python, but I'm not sure what other language uses `%` as a string interpolation operator.

Comment: Sorry I am using Javascript, the % sign is some answer provided in a similar question.

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in way in jmespath or the search function to template values into the query string, but you can safely embed JSON literals with backticks, however your language allows it.

```js
var name = "Annie";
var result = jmespath.search(JSONdata, 'Items[?Name == `' + JSON.stringify(name).replace('`','\\`') + '`]');
```

We need to convert the string to JSON, [*escape any backticks in that string*](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions) and then wrap it in backticks. Let's wrap that into a function to make it a bit nicer to read:

```
function jmespath_escape(item) {
    return '`' + JSON.stringify(item).replace('`','\\`') + '`';
}

var name = "Annie";
var result = jmespath.search(JSONdata, 'Items[?Name == ' + jmespath_escape(name) + ']');
```