# JMESPath Query in Ansible

Tags: json, jenkins, ansible, yaml, jmespath

---

---  EDIT  ---

**Partial-Solution**: Messed around with the JMESPath syntax and was able to successfully get a match for the first test case (without the optional variable) using:

```
jmesquery: "{{ datacenter }}{{ subcategory }}.{{ refine_hosts }}.[*][].[*][][]"
```

---

I am writing an Ansible Playbook that takes a list of hosts from a network server, parses the JSON list, and finds hostnames that matches the user's input when they deploy the playbook as a Jenkin's Job through it's API.

The issue I am encountering is that I am unable to successfully query the JSON host list. Currently, I am only trying to run the following test case:

```
datacenter: a
subcategory: bc
refine_hosts: QA
```

However, the final version of this playbook should be able to take in values for `datacenter`, `subcategory`, and `refine_hosts` with an optional input value of `host_type`. An example test case including the optional input value would be the following:

```
datacenter: a
subcategory: bc
refine_hosts: QA
host_type: WEBSITE
```

In my playbook, I am using JMESPath within the following task:

```
- name: Build HOSTS list
  set_fact:
    hosts_list: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: '%%datacenter%%-%%subcategory%%.%%refine_hosts%%.[*][*][][]'
```

The JSON host list is structured in the following manner (I am unable to edit the structure of the host list, but it will always follow the following structure nonetheless):

```json
{
   "a-bc":{
      "all":{
         "webServer":[

         ],
         "archive":[
            "someHostAlias-123.privateDomain.com"
         ],
         "central":[
            "someHostAlias-456.privateDomain.com"
         ]
      },
      "QA":{
         "xyz":{
            "INBOUND_HTTP":[
               "someHostAlias-789.privateDomain.com"
            ],
            "WEBSITE":[
               "someHostAlias-1011.privateDomain.com"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have been using the following websites for this issue:

- [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)
- [Ansible JMESPath Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries)
- [JSONPath Expression Tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#)
- [StackOverflow: How to Use Variable in JMESPath Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680158/how-to-use-variable-in-jmespath-expression)
- [Gitter: JMESPath/chat](https://gitter.im/jmespath/chat?at=5e3b9f1a433e1d40399b04d5)

I apologize if the query seems obvious, this is my first attempt at an Ansible Playbook. All help/feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: All of the above comes down to debugging your [jmespath/json_query](https://jmespath.org/) expression which does not return what you expect. IMO you should rephrase this question to lower the quantity of details and focus only on this part by providing an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and explaining very precisely what you expect as a user entry and as output.

Comment: I strongly recommend changing "Role1" into a dynamic inventory script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issue of your query is that you are confusing `[*]` — a [list projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#list-and-slice-projections) — that selects all the elements of a list with `.*` — an [object projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#object-projections) — that selects all the properties of a dictionary.

So, one solution in JMESPath, would be to do:

```yaml
jmesquery: >-
  "{{ datacenter }}-{{ subcategory }}".{{ refine_hosts }}.*.
  {{ host_type if host_type | default('') != '' else '*' }}[] | []
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
      loop: "{{ fake_user_input }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ jmesquery }}"
      vars:
        jmesquery: >-
          "{{ datacenter }}-{{ subcategory }}".{{ refine_hosts }}.*.
          {{ host_type if host_type | default('') != '' else '*' }}[] | []
        
        datacenter: "{{ item.datacenter }}"
        subcategory: "{{ item.subcategory }}"
        refine_hosts: "{{ item.refine_hosts }}"
        host_type: "{{ item.host_type | default('') }}"

        fake_user_input:
          - datacenter: a
            subcategory: bc
            refine_hosts: QA
            host_type: WEBSITE
          - datacenter: a
            subcategory: bc
            refine_hosts: QA

        jsondata:
          a-bc:
            all:
              webServer: []
              archive:
              - someHostAlias-123.privateDomain.com
              central:
              - someHostAlias-456.privateDomain.com
            QA:
              xyz:
                INBOUND_HTTP:
                - someHostAlias-789.privateDomain.com
                WEBSITE:
                - someHostAlias-1011.privateDomain.com
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item="a-bc".QA.*. WEBSITE[] | []) => 
  msg:
  - someHostAlias-1011.privateDomain.com
ok: [localhost] => (item="a-bc".QA.*. *[] | []) => 
  msg:
  - someHostAlias-789.privateDomain.com
  - someHostAlias-1011.privateDomain.com
```